# How to Map a ValueObject Collection with Foreign Keys in FluentNHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I've been looking all over for an example of this, but it seems pretty uncommon.  Hopefully some NHibernate guru will know.

I have the following class which, by my understanding of Value Objects, is a Value Object.  Assume every user has the ability to assign one or more tags to any Question (think Stack Overflow).  The Tags don't need a primary key, but they do hold references to the User and Question, unlike most of the examples of ValueObjects I see out there.

```
public class Tag : ValueObject
{
     public virtual User User { get; set; }
     public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
     public virtual string TagName { get; set; }
}

public class User 
{
     public virtual IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
     public virtual IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Anyway, I am getting the following error:

{"The entity 'Tag' doesn't have an Id mapped. Use the Id method to map your identity property. For example: Id(x => x.Id)."}

I have the following Fluent NHibernate mapping for User and Question:

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<XXX> mapping)
        {
            mapping.HasMany(x => x.Tags).Component(c =>
            {
                c.Map(x => x.TagName);
                c.Map(x => x.Question);
                c.Map(x => x.User);
            });
        }
```

As always, any thought greatly appreciated.

Late Update:  Okay, so, maybe this isn't a value object.  It doesn't need an identity, but I guess it's not something that could be used in multiple places, either.  Any way to handle this without forcing a useless Id field on my object?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<XXX> mapping)
    {
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.Tags).AsBag().Component(c =>
        {
            c.Map(x => x.TagName);
            c.References(x => x.Question);
            c.References(x => x.User);
        });
    }
```

but you cant query (list all) tags then because its a value object.